# Can't get jQuery UI drag helper to change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, draggable, helper

I'm trying to have a `.draggable()` object's helper change according to where it is on the screen. To do it, I'm using the helper's set function, with the value being HTML generated from a separate template. By using `console.log()` statements to see what the helper is, I can see that the HTML has changed appropriately (at least I'm fairly certain), but the helper itself is not changing on-screen. For some context, this is CoffeeScript in a Backbone.js view. Here's my code:

```
$('#syllabus').droppable({
  scope: "components",
  over: (event, ui) ->
    $('#new_plaintext_button').draggable("option", "helper", $(JST["backbone/templates/components/box"]()))
  out: ->
    $('#new_plaintext_button').draggable("option", "helper", "clone")
})
```

To clarify, the helper starts out as a clone, and when I hover over the object with the correct scope, it should change to the new HTML object from the template. When I leave the scope, it should return to the clone. Here's the jQuery object for the helper before I change it and after:

```
[i.fa.fa-3x.fa-file-text-o.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle.ui-draggable-dragging, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: i#new_plaintext_button.fa.fa-3x.fa-file-text-o.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle, constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
[div#component_box, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
```

And as a final note, I've styled this new div in CSS with visible features, so I know it's not the case that my div is just empty so I can't see it. If anyone has any idea why this isn't working, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: That is not a jquery object. What  you've shared is just plain text.

Comment: @TJ Can you try to help me a little more? I've placed the HTML into a jQuery selector, so I'm not quite sure how it's only plain text. If it is, how would I go about making it a jQuery object? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share minimal code required to reproduce what you have so far..? or an online demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @TJ here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/peexa00m/ I seem to have trouble putting more than one line in the `over` and `out` functions, hence why I left out print statements - I'm still pretty new to CoffeeScript, that's why. But I did try a print and saw that the object being created is the same I indicated in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out part of my problem. One issue is that in order to change the helper, you have to pass a function as the parameter, not a jQuery object. The other issue is that when the helper is changed, the view isn't updated, so you'll only see the change if you drag the `.draggable` object a second time. This clarifies things for me, but I still need to figure out how to get the new helper to appear during the original drag. Any advice is appreciated.